# Bootstrap 4 col responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am using Bootstrap and have some problem with responsive layout.
I have 2 rows where I am using 4 columns like this:
[setup-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kaHY.png)

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                some image
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On resolution < 1200px it change to something like this: [setup-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py1sW.png)

How can I change it to setup col like this: [setup-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nJrQ.png)

I was looking for some part of Bootstrap code which is responsible for that, but with no succes. Is there any way to overwrite in my 'style.css'?

Comment: What code do you add inside the card divs ? If your bootstrap copy is unchanged, the problem probably comes from the `some image / some text` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
<div class="col">
```

You may use:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
```

You can read more information about Bootstrap grid by this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp